# Categorize single column of text into multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro that will categorize data in one column into multiple columns based on the item type. The data I am trying to categorize is a list of contracts with meta-data on the items in the contract.

The raw data looks like this:

```
Contract No Contract Name           Item Type   Item Description
111111      Chocolate Supplies      POTS        5"
111111      Chocolate Supplies      POTS        10"
111111      Chocolate Supplies      POTS        15"
111111      Chocolate Supplies      PANS        5"
111111      Chocolate Supplies      PANS        10"
111111      Chocolate Supplies      PANS        15"
111111      Chocolate Supplies      KNIVES      Paring knife
111111      Chocolate Supplies      SILVERWARE  Salad fork
111111      Chocolate Supplies      SILVERWARE  Dinner fork
111111      Chocolate Supplies      SILVERWARE  Dessert fork
111111      Chocolate Supplies      SILVERWARE  Dessert spoon
111111      Chocolate Supplies      SILVERWARE  Soup spoon
22222       Soups and Salads Order      POTS        10"
22222       Soups and Salads Order      POTS        15"
22222       Soups and Salads Order      PANS        15"
22222       Soups and Salads Order      KNIVES      Butter knife
22222       Soups and Salads Order      KNIVES      Bread knife
22222       Soups and Salads Order      KNIVES      Paring knife
22222       Soups and Salads Order      SILVERWARE  Soup spoon
```

The final data needs to look like this (edited to include image):
[image: Final Format of Report]

```
Contract    Contract Name           POTS    PANS    KNIVES          SILVERWARE
111111      Chocolate Supplies      5"      5"      Paring knife    Salad fork
                                    10"     10"                     Dinner fork                         
                                    15"     15"                     Dessert fork
                                                                    Dessert spoon
                                                                    Soup spoon
22222       Soups and Salads Order  10"     15"     Butter knife    Soup spoon
                                    15"             Bread knife 
                                                    Paring knife
```

**# What I've tried so far #**
The current crude solution I am using is to:
- Run the query
- Paste the data into excel
- Create a pivot
- Use a series of count, offset and indirect formulas to reorganize the data as needed
- Since the above process leaves empty rows between each section of contracts, I copy-paste the data into a new worksheet, put an Autofilter and remove the blank rows
... and voila, that's the final report.

**# Possible VBA solution #**
I found [this tutorial](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2010/03/10/categorize-values-into-multiple-columns-using-vba-in-excel/) which seems to do exactly what I want, except for the problem where I need the macro to start a new section when the contract no. changes. I don't know how to get the VBA code below to also check for the contract no.

I'd love any help you could send my way. Thanks in advance!

**# Code from [tutorial on get-digital-help [dot] com](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2010/03/10/categorize-values-into-multiple-columns-using-vba-in-excel/) by Oscar. #**
This is *not* my code, and I give complete credit to Oscar's tutorial for getting me going in the right direction.

```
Sub Categorizedatatocolumns()
Dim rng As Range
Dim dest As Range
Dim vrb As Boolean
Dim i As Integer
Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4")
vrb = False
Do While rng <> ""
Set dest = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A20")
Do While dest <> ""
If rng.Value = dest.Value Then
vrb = True
End If
Set dest = dest.Offset(0, 1)
Loop
If vrb = False Then
dest.Value = rng.Value
dest.Font.bold = True
End If
vrb = False
Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
Loop
Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4")
Do While rng <> ""
Set dest = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A20")
Do While dest <> ""
If rng.Value = dest.Value Then
i = 0
Do While dest <> ""
Set dest = dest.Offset(1, 0)
i = i + 1
Loop
Set rng = rng.Offset(0, 1)
dest.Value = rng.Value
Set rng = rng.Offset(0, -1)
Set dest = dest.Offset(-i, 0)
End If
Set dest = dest.Offset(0, 1)
Loop
Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using pivot table which will give similar output.

[image]

Turn off the Subtotal and show data in tabular form for all fields.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Santosh, thanks for responding but this doesn't get me the 'item types' going across the columns. I've added a new screenshot to show what the final report format looks like.